# C++ Debian SDL segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, g++, debian, sdl

I am using SDL to create a quiz game program. The code compiles fine, but when I run the output executable, I get a segmentation fault. I am trying to blit a button onto the screen. Here is my code:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_ttf.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#undef main

void ablit(SDL_Surface* source, SDL_Surface* destination, int x, int y){
        SDL_Rect offset;
        offset.x = x;
        offset.y = y;
        SDL_BlitSurface(source, NULL, destination, &offset);
}

void acreatebutton(int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Color fill, SDL_Surface*                    
screenSurface, const char* buttontext, int fontsize, SDL_Color textfill){
        SDL_Rect* buttonrect;
        buttonrect->x = x;
        buttonrect->y = y;
        buttonrect->w = w;
        buttonrect->h = h;
        int fillint = SDL_MapRGB(screenSurface -> format, fill.r, fill.g, 
fill.b);
    SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, buttonrect, fillint);
    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf", fontsize);
    SDL_Surface* buttontextsurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font, buttontext, textfill);
    ablit(buttontextsurface, screenSurface, 300, 300);
    TTF_CloseFont(font);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv){
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
        TTF_Init();
        SDL_Window* screen = SDL_CreateWindow("Quiz Game",   SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 500, 400,SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);
    SDL_Surface* screenSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface( screen );
    SDL_FillRect (screenSurface, NULL, SDL_MapRGB( screenSurface->format, 0, 0, 255 ) );
    SDL_Color black = {0, 0, 0};
    TTF_Font* afont = TTF_OpenFont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf", 35);
    SDL_Surface* aQuiz_Game = TTF_RenderText_Solid(afont, "Quiz Game", black);
    ablit(aQuiz_Game, screenSurface, 150, 50);
    acreatebutton(175, 350, 200, 50, black, screenSurface, "Take Quiz", 35, black);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface( screen );
    SDL_Event windowEvent;
    while (true){
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&windowEvent))
        {
            if (windowEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP &&
            windowEvent.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) break;
        }
        SDL_GL_SwapWindow(screen);
    }
    TTF_CloseFont(afont);
    SDL_Quit();
    TTF_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Th ablit function is for blitting, and the abutton function is for creating button images.

Comment: Try to use a debugger to know when the SegFault happens, and if you still can't resolve your problem post your debugger's output here. Another thing is that your never check the return value of the functions, so if some surface or font is null, you can't be warned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should show, where does you code gets to the segfault, otherwise it's difficult to guess.

**First** culprit could be the line:

```
TTF_Font* afont = TTF_OpenFont("/usr/share/fonts/truetype/droid/DroidSansMono.ttf", 35);
```

You create the font, but doesn't check if it succeeded. If the font file doesn't exist on you computer, you will probably get a segmentation fault.

**Second** problem is in the function `acreatebutton`. You declare `buttonrect` as a pointer, but never initialize it! It's an UB and may do anything, e.g. crashing your program.
In this case you probably don't need it to be a pointer at all, so changing it to a simple variable on the stack should work:

```
SDL_Rect buttonrect;
buttonrect.x = x;
/* more code ... */
SDL_FillRect(screenSurface, &buttonrect, fillint);
```

You can find both these problems very easily.

1. Enable all warnings. GCC will tell you about uninitialized pointer when compiling (I recommend adding `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`  to you `g++` flags).
2. Learn to use a debugger (`GDB` is an excelent one). The would tell you everything.
3. Try a memory sanitizer (compile with `-fsanitize=address -g`). It will very nicely show you, what went wrong.